# Metamask Staked Tokens not loading

Tags: metamask, staking

I am trying to look at my account where I have staked my OX to review how much ether I have earned.  I am loading my wallet with metamask, and I have done this many times in the past, and I sit in an infinite loop of "Loading, grabbing data for yoru wallet".

How do I get my information to load.  I also noticed that none of the staking nodes are showing.  I am using Edge as my browser.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the wallet on the phone (every time it gets stuck on the computer, but never on the phone), metamask sometimes gets stuck, it may be the network environment or may be congestion in the chain